# Retrieve maximum value of an element in a list R

Tags: r, list

I have a list, `mylist`, that has different elements: `a`, `b` and `c`. The list has length `n`. So if I type `mylist[[1]]["c"]` in my console I retrieve a value of 5,
if I type `mylist[[3]]["c"]` I retrieve a value of 9 and so on.

What I would like to do is find a way to retrieve which index of the list has the highest value in the element `c`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sapply` + `[` to retrieve the `"c"` elements and `which.max` to get the index of the maximum value.

```r
myList <- list(c(a = 1, b = 0, c = 3), c(a = 3, b = 5, c = 2))
unname(which.max(sapply(myList, `[`, "c")))
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason of the use of "`[`", I don't understand this part inside the sapply funcion, where it expects a list and a function. And if for example I wanna know which index of the list has the element "c" the value 3 for example, how could I achieve that? I would like to understand the logic, thanks.